# setAuth is not updating the auth state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

My previous post got associated with a post that didn't answer my question and closed.

I am attempting to create a ProtectedRoutes component, however, I can't seem to get the auth state to update.

It should check if there is a cookie stored, and if so, set auth as true. Then if auth is true, it redirects to the auth component, otherwise to the landing/login page.

The auth page always redirects back to the landing page. The state is never updating to true. I have searched everywhere, and I cannot figure out why the state won't update.

Is it even possible to create this ProtectedRoutes component this way?

ProtectedRoutes.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();


export default function ProtectedRoutes({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
    //get cookie from browser if logged in
    const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token) {
            setAuth(true);
        }
    },[token]);
    
    return auth ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/" />
}
```

App.js

```
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./App.css";
import Register from "./Register";
import Login from "./Login";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Account from "./Account";
import FreeComponent from "./FreeComponent";
import AuthComponent from "./AuthComponent";
import Private from "./ProtectedRoutes";
import ProtectedRoutes from "./ProtectedRoutes";

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col className="text-center">
          <h1 className="header">React Authentication Tutorial</h1>

          <section id="navigation">
            <a href="/">Home</a>
            <a href="/free">Free Component</a>
            <a href="/auth">Auth Component</a>
          </section>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      
      {/* Routes */ }
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={ <Account /> } />
        <Route exact path="/free" element={ <FreeComponent /> } />
        <Route path="/auth" element={<ProtectedRoutes component={AuthComponent} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AuthComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function AuthComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="text-center">Auth Component</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to even hold `auth` as an item of React state ?

If everything is driven from the cookie with the token in it, then there's no need to *also* store it in state *and then* have a `useEffect` in turn listening for that.

I think what's probably happening is your page renders the first time (i.e. before your `useEffect` has run) and immediately commences the `Navigate` path, because `auth` is still `false` (its initial value). Your `useEffect` does run, but it's *too late* - your app has already moved on to showing the `Navigate` component.

Try this:

```
export default function ProtectedRoutes({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    //get cookie from browser if logged in
    const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");
    
    return token ? <Component /> : <Navigate to="/" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.